# Javascript: onkeyup not getting along with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have 2 functions attached to even listeners in a form. An `onsubmit` attached to a `<form>` and an `onkeyup` attached to an `<input>` within the form.

The form has no search button, user must hit enter to submit the form. Problem is that hitting enter triggers the onkeyup AFTER the onsubmit.

the onkeyup function shows a message to "hit enter to search", then the onsubmit is supposed to replace that text with a loading bar until AJAX return the results. Instead of showing my loading bar, the script show the text "press enter to search".

Here is a simplification...

```
<script>
    function doThings(){
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />";
        //Ajax Stuff
        return false;
    }
    function checkThings(){
        var someCondition = true;
        if(someCondition){
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Press ENTER to search.";
        }
    }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return doThings()">
    <input type="text" id="q" onkeyup="checkThings();" />
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

What can I do to ensure that the onsubmit function is executed AFTER the onkeyup function, otherwise prevent the onkeyup function from executing when the ENTER key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple workaround is to wrap showing loading bar in setTimeout call to execute it in next event loop:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />"
}, 0);
```

**EDIT:** Another way, if you, actually, want to *prevent the onkeyup function from executing when the ENTER key is pressed* is to check keycode in event handler. "Enter" key code is 13:

```
<input type="text" id="q" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode !== 13) checkThings();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can prevent this execution is by setting a boolean in your `doThings()` function stating an Ajax call was made. when the Ajax call is returned you can flag that boolean off.

```
var submitted = false; 
function doThings(){
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />";
    submitted = true;
    //Ajax Stuff
    //on Ajax success make sure to set submitted back to false
    return false;
}
function checkThings(){
    var someCondition = true;
    if(someCondition && !submitted){
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Press ENTER to search.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution I was torn between which answer to choose. Thank you for the suggestion.